# iPhone: how to quantize the position of a touched object

Tags: iphone, touch, geometry, quantization

Hi all you smart people out there!
I want to create a touch interface to an iOS app, that allows the user to drag an object on the screen around.
However, this object should be restricted to move along the perimeter of a circle, so that if the user is trying to drag the object outside that path, it would stick to the nearest point of that circle.
I have done some iPhone programming, but my math is poor. Please help!

Comment: I'm really just at the beginning, so there is no code yet. I will be able to find out where the user touches the screen, and I can move a bitmap to that position. What I would need to know, is how to define a circle, and how to calculate the point in the circle that is the closest to the touch point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you have to do is set the frame of the view to follow the equation of a circle (of the form: `(x-a)^2 + (y-b)^2 = r^2`). Once you detect the touch point, you can restrict the view's frame according to the x or the y coordinate of the touch point (both ways are the same).

```
#define circleRadius 60.0 // r in the above eqtn
#define circlesCenter_X 160.0 // a in the above eqtn
#define circlesCenter_Y 200.0 // b in the above eqtn
#define circleCenter_y(x) sqrtf(circleRadius*circleRadius - (x-circlesCenter_X)*(x-circlesCenter_X))

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:firstPieceView] anyObject];
    CGPoint previousLocation = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat delta_x = previousLocation.x - location.x; // constrained by x in this eg.
    CGFloat newX = firstPieceView.center.x-delta_x;
    // do limit the view's x-coordinate for possible solutions
    if(newX<circlesCenter_X - circleRadius)
        newX = circlesCenter_X - circleRadius;
    if(newX>circlesCenter_X + circleRadius)
        newX = circlesCenter_X + circleRadius;
    firstPieceView.center = CGPointMake(newX, circleCenter_y(newX)*(location.y>=circlesCenter_Y?1:-1) + circlesCenter_Y);
}
```

**EDIT-** Better solution:

```
#define circleRadius 60.0 // r in the above eqtn
#define circlesCenter_X 160.0 // a in the above eqtn
#define circlesCenter_Y 200.0 // b in the above eqtn
#define slope(x,y) (y-circlesCenter_Y)/(x-circlesCenter_X)
#define pointOnCircle_X(m) circleRadius/(sqrtf(m*m + 1))

-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    UITouch *touch = [[event touchesForView:self.view] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    CGFloat slope;
    CGPoint pointOnCircle;
    if(location.x==circlesCenter_X){// case for infinite slope
        pointOnCircle.x = circlesCenter_X;
        if(location.x<circlesCenter_X){
            pointOnCircle.y = circlesCenter_Y - circleRadius;
        }else{
            pointOnCircle.y = circlesCenter_Y + circleRadius;
        }
    }else{
        slope = slope(location.x,location.y);
        if(location.x<circlesCenter_X){
            pointOnCircle.x = circlesCenter_X - pointOnCircle_X(slope);
        }else{
            pointOnCircle.x = circlesCenter_X + pointOnCircle_X(slope);
        }
        pointOnCircle.y = slope * (pointOnCircle.x - circlesCenter_X) + circlesCenter_Y;
    }
    firstPieceView.center = pointOnCircle;
}
```

*This can be applied similarly for `Android`, `Blackberry`, etc too!*

Comment: Thanks, that fits in what I remember from high school! I will try it immediately, and reward you with a green tick!

Comment: Actually, this works only partially: it does do the lower part of a circle, but as soon as it enters the upper part, it throws an exception ('CALayerInvalidGeometry', reason: 'CALayer position contains NaN: [262 nan]'). Also, I'm a bit confused by the 'button' and the 'btnLeft'. How do they relate to each other and to the "yourView"?

Comment: Actually I had picked up this code from a custom semi-circular menu I had created, hence the unknown variables remained. Now back to the exceptions: First of all, I hadn't put any conditions on the limits of x. The `NaN` you get is when you try to square root a negative number(I've added the conditions in the answer). Also, since this is a quadratic eqn, it has two solutions! I've edited the answer to incorporate that!

Comment: Dear tipycalFlow, thank you so much for your efforts! With the risk of making a complete fool out of myself, this is what I did: I took Apple's Touches example (http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Touches/Introduction/Intro.html) and replaced the touchesMoved method with yours. I substituted yourView with firstPieceView. Somehow, the firstPieceView just doesn't move when touched. I then replaced yourView with self.view, as an experiment. [continues]

Comment: This moved the whole viewController, which is not what I need, but it at least shows, that still the movement seems to be restricted to the lower half of the circle, this time without exception though.

Comment: Updated! Replace `yourView` with your view and keep `self.view` as it is

Comment: Hmm, same observations as above. I guess I'm doing something stupid. Would you have a working sample project, so I can see where I go wrong? I apologize for my insistence and cannot stress enough my gratitude for your time and brain cycles.

Comment: Oops, I had mentally written down the equations and had not verified the changes but I've found the mistake I was making. I'll have to give it about half an hour to give you a better solution...

Comment: Unfortunately, the line "slope = slope(location.x, location.y);" gives the following error: "Called object type 'CGFloat' (aka 'float') is not a function or function pointer"

Comment: Might be due to your xCode settings! Updated with a function.

Comment: I'm running the latest beta [Version 4.5 (4G144l)]. The latest code gives a warning on "pointOnCircle.x = circlesCenter_X - pointOnCircle_X(slope);" ("Implicit declaration of function 'pointOnCircle_X' is invalid in C99") and subsequently produces Mach-O linker errors during compilation.

Comment: You can make a method for `pointOnCircle_X` too. Or, write down the macro definitions outside your class implementation, right below `#import`!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15953/discussion-between-sjakelien-and-tipycalflow)